# "the leaders met 'at' or 'in' the g20 summit"

Tags: prepositions

When the word "summit" is used in the sense of an assembly of leaders, which proposition should be used? At or in?
For example; 'the leaders met AT/IN the g20 summit shared their concerns over the prevailing recession'

Comment: Hello, Jithu. Have you checked [online](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1ASRM_enGB617GB618&q=met+summit+meeting&oq=met+summit+meeting&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10708.12096.0.12732.4.4.0.0.0.0.79.264.4.4.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.143...0i13k1j0i7i30k1.6AuDwrPmjak) to see which **preposition** is normally used?

Comment: Yes I have already.. I came across lines like "they met for the summit". Had I already had an answer, I wouldn't be asking this question. Thank you Edwin for your suggestion anyways.

Comment: googling "met at the summit" (with quotes) => 4.3 million results.  googling "met in the summit" => 3 results.  That's a useful strategy which you can reuse in future.

Comment: Then, it's at the summit.. Thank you guys for your quick response.

Comment: This is always assuming that *summit* is used as a noun. It could be an adjective, as in: *they met for summit talks/ for a summit conference* etc. In this case *for* has a role to play.

Answer (score 1):

**'The leaders met `at` the g20 summit shared their concerns over the prevailing recession.'**

The summit is an event. It refers to what happened *at* a particular time *at* a particular place.

The meetings at the summit were activities of organized groups in which one may be included so the leaders were *in* the meeting but *at* the summit.  There is a subtle difference between being *at* a meeting and being *in* a meeting.  A spectator is *at* a meeting not *in* it.  In the same way, the spectators at a football match are *at* the game but only the players are *in* the game.

Comment: That was a nice explanation

Answer (score 0):

The term "summit" in your usage is accepted shorthand for "summit meeting". The leaders would share concerns IN the summit meeting. If you instead wrote that the leaders met AT the summit, I'd assume they were congregating on a mountaintop somewhere... :)

Answer (score 0):

Most commentators would use *at* for both yet strictly, *in* would indicate in the official chambers and prolly on summit business, while *at* could equally include meeting in the bar afterwards and discussing nothing but sports.

By the way, I don't understand why anyone would want to down-vote that perfectly reasonable question.